# Mailhandler.php assistance needed

Tags: javascript, forms

I do not understand how to make the MailHandler from my template's form submission work. I downloaded a template that I've been working on manually using DW6 alone, but I can't figure out exactly what to change in order to make the form in the Contact section send me the form info to my email address. Any help is much appreciated.

From my index.html

```
<form action="#" id="ContactForm">  
                                    <div class="success"> Enviado!&nbsp; <strong>Nos contactaremos a la brevedad</strong></div> 
                                        <fieldset class="left"> 
                                                    <div class="block">
                                                    <label class="name">
                                                        <span class="textStyle3">Nombre</span>
                                                        <span class="bg"><input type="text" value="" class="input"></span>
                                                        <span class="error">*Éste no es un nombre válido.</span> <span class="empty">*Campo Obligatorio.</span> </label>
                                                     <label class="email">
                                                        <span class="textStyle3">e-mail</span>
                                                        <span class="bg"><input type="text" value="" class="input"></span>
                                                        <span class="error">*Dirección de email no válida.</span> <span class="empty">*Campo Obligatorio.</span> </label>

                                                     </div>
                                                     <div class="block">
                                                     <label class="message">
                                                        <span class="textStyle3">Mensaje</span>
                                                        <span class="bg"><textarea rows="1" cols="2"></textarea></span>
                                                        <span class="error">*Este mensaje es muy corto.</span> <span class="empty">*Campo Obligatorio.</span> </label>
                                                     </div>
                                                      <div class="formBtn right">
                                                            <a href="#" data-type="submit" class="more">Enviar</a>
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div class="formBtn left">
                                                             <a href="#" data-type="reset" class="more">Limpiar</a>
                                                      </div>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </form>
```

From my MailHandler.php

```
<?php
$owner_email = $_POST["owner_email"];
$headers = 'From:' . $_POST["email"];
$subject = 'A message from your site visitor ' . $_POST["name"];
$messageBody = "";

if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}else{
    $headers = '';
}
if($_POST['state']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}    
if($_POST['fax']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
    $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
}

try{
    if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
        throw new Exception('mail failed');
    }else{
        echo 'mail sent';
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
?>
```

From my scripts.js

```
//forms
;(function($){
$.fn.forms=function(o){
    return this.each(function(){
        var th=$(this)
            ,_=th.data('forms')||{
                errorCl:'error',
                emptyCl:'empty',
                invalidCl:'invalid',
                notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                successCl:'success',
                successShow:'4000',
                mailHandlerURL:'bin/MailHandler.php',
                ownerEmail:'info@pacificbayhotel.com',
                stripHTML:true,
                smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                targets:'input,textarea',
                controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                validate:true,
                rx:{
                    ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                    ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                    ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                    ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                    ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                    ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                },
                preFu:function(){
                    _.labels.each(function(){
                        var label=$(this),
                            inp=$(_.targets,this),
                            defVal=inp.val(),
                            trueVal=(function(){
                                        var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                        return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                    })()
                        trueVal!=defVal
                            &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                        label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                        inp
                            .bind('focus',function(){
                                inp.val()==defVal
                                    &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                            })
                            .bind('blur',function(){
                                _.validateFu(label)
                                if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                    inp.val(defVal)
                                    ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))                                          
                            })
                            .bind('keyup',function(){
                                label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                    &&_.validateFu(label)
                            })
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                    })
                    _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                },
                isRequired:function(el){                            
                    return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                },
                isValid:function(el){                           
                    var ret=true
                    $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                        if(el.is(k))
                            ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())                                      
                    })
                    return ret                          
                },
                isEmpty:function(el){
                    var tmp
                    return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                },
                validateFu:function(el){                            
                    el.each(function(){
                        var th=$(this)
                            ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                            ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                            ,valid=_.isValid(th)                                

                        if(empty&&req)
                            _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                        else
                            _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                        if(!empty)
                            if(valid)
                                _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))                             
                    })
                },
                getValFromLabel:function(label){
                    var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                        ,defVal=label.data('defVal')                                
                    return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                }
                ,submitFu:function(){
                    _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                    if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                            data:{
                                name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                                state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                                message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                            },
                            success: function(){
                                _.showFu()
                            }
                        })          
                },
                showFu:function(){
                    _.success.slideDown(function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            _.success.slideUp()
                            _.form.trigger('reset')
                        },_.successShow)
                    })
                },
                controlsFu:function(){
                    $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                        var th=$(this)
                        th
                            .bind('click',function(){
                                _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                return false
                            })
                    })
                },
                showErrorFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                },
                hideErrorFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                },
                showEmptyFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                    _.hideErrorFu(label)
                },
                hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                },
                init:function(){
                    _.form=_.me                     
                    _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                    _.preFu()

                    _.controlsFu()

                    _.form
                        .bind('submit',function(){
                            if(_.validate)
                                _.submitFu()
                            else
                                _.form[0].submit()
                            return false
                        })
                        .bind('reset',function(){
                            _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                            _.labels.each(function(){
                                var th=$(this)
                                _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                            })
                        })
                    _.form.trigger('reset')
                }
            }
        _.me||_.init(_.me=th.data({forms:_}))
        typeof o=='object'
            &&$.extend(_,o)
    })
}
})(jQuery)
$(window).load(function(){
$('#ContactForm').forms({
    ownerEmail:'#'
})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In your scripts.js find this line ownerEmail:'#'

and in that field you give you your own email like ownerEmail:'info@mysite.com'

Answer (score 0):

you need to place your email address on your index page (or contact.html) where the script is loaded.
look for :

```
<script>
    $(function(){


        //  Initialize Contact Form
        $('#YOUR_FORM_ID').forms({
            ownerEmail:'#' //CHANGE # TO YOUR E-MAIL
        });
    })
</script>
```